# SSIS Scripting Task: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: vb.net, ssis, tls1.2

I have a server (operating system is Windows 2012 server - yes I need to update; just dread the process) that has been running the below code in SSIS for years (5+)).  A couple of months ago, it just stopped working (I haven't changed anything, nor has anyone else even looked at it as it was running just fine).  I now get the error: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"  This is just a simple task in VB.Net that goes out to a government website (crop insurance info) and downloads information. No credentials are needed (username or password).  This website is made specifically for this purpose.

This code will fail every time at "response As WebResponse = webReq.GetResponse()".  I'm running SQL Server 2017 along with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in both machines.

I copy and paste this same script into another server we have, and it runs just fine.  I'm at a loss.  Any suggestions?

```
   Public Sub Main()

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


    Dim remoteUri As String = "external website"

    ' The downloaded resource ends up in the variable named content.
    Dim content = New MemoryStream()


    Try
        Using response As WebResponse = webReq.GetResponse()
            ' Get the data stream that is associated with the specified URL.
            Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                ' Read the bytes in responseStream and copy them to content.
                responseStream.CopyTo(content)
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Nothing about this code snippet is [tag:vbscript] would suspect it's [tag:vb.net].

Comment: You are correct.  Sorry about the confusion.  In SSIS it is called a VB script task.  I will change accordingly.

Comment: It's because it was originally VBScript in earlier versions but when they shifted to .Net they didn't change the name.

Comment: Do you know which .NET Framework you are running under? The code you posted _should_ work for .NET Framework 4.5. Ideally you would target 4.6 or higher to support TLS1.2

Comment: .NET Framework is version 4.5

Comment: It's not just about the SSL Protocol. Missing some required cipher suites also generates the same exception / aborts the transaction. Your older server is most probably not meeting the minimum requirements in this department

Comment: I'm going to bite the bullet and upgrade my windows server software to 2022.  I can't do that until Monday.  I'll keep you all posted.

Comment: Updating the OS worked.